# How to publish to a GCP PubSub topic from inside a Cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-pubsub, cloudflare-workers

Is it possible to publish to a GCP PubSub topic via a basic HTTP request? I have a Cloudflare worker from which I'd like to publish directly to a topic. I originally tried bundling the NodeJS module, but webpack (via wrangler) was unable to build due to dependencies (specifically `tls`) that are  unavailable in the server worker environment.

It seems API keys aren't supported on the PubSub API and I can't for the life of me find a way to use a service account *without* using an SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. There is the [publish method that uses REST](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish), but it requires OAuth2.0 authorization. I'm not sure if you'll run into the same issues as using the NodeJS client library, but if so, you'll have to use an intermediate service (i.e. Cloud Functions/Compute Engine/App Engine) that exposes an HTTP endpoint that *can* do the authentication for you.

For more information on using OAuth2.0, see this link here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication#user-accounts

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Do you know if it requires you to continuously refresh tokens or can I create a persistent OAuth token to use indefinitely? I'd rather not create an intermediary webservice as that sort of defeats the purpose of having the topic to begin with. AWS's SNS seems to let you sign requests and make them via HTTP. PubSub doesn't have anything similar?

Comment: I believe that all access tokens has an expiration date, so you will need to retrieve retrieve new access tokens via the refresh token. To answer your other question, unfortunately the only other supported method is authentication with service accounts which you already tried.

Comment: For more clarification, we do have an older HTTP-based client library which uses c [discovery docs](https://pubsub.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1) to make the request, but that still depends on [`google-auth-library`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) which most likely still won't work since it requires TLS. I think the OAauth2 way is the only way this will work with Cloudflare Workers. You could also look into just replacing Cloudflare Workers with Cloud Functions (which offers a similar serverless pay-per-execution environment)